# Return rows that do not contain certain text

Tags: sql-server

I have a query in SQL Server to select all the data from a database.

```
SELECT * FROM DatabaseName
```

Is there a way to select all the data that does not contain a certain phrase.

For example if I have a table that contains

```
Contain
Contain1
Contain2
Exclude1
Exclude2
Contain3
Contain4
Exclude3
```

and I want to exclude the text `Exclude`

it would only return

```
Contain
Contain1
Contain2
Contain3
Contain4
```

Unfortunately every row is very large (>500000 characters) so I am trying to find an efficient way to do this.

Comment: what is the datatype of the column?

Comment: I didn't even know that was possible. (It's not, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms177634.aspx.) Surely it would be more efficient to convert the data to an XML format before extracting?

Comment: What makes it not possible?

Comment: What is the issue with using Like operator? have you tried it?

Comment: Using `Not Like` was able to solve my issue (not sure why user removed the answer)

Comment: that has the potential to be very expensive, given your  row size.  Have you looked at the cost of doing that, in terms of CPU, disk, etc.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE [Column] NOT LIKE 'Exclude%'
```

Comment: This was able to solve my issue. Not sure if it is efficient but it is a simple method to exclude the results I do not want

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you might benefit from a [FULLTEXT INDEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).